# How to pass the array data to Custom UITableView in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am struggling this for 2 days. Please help me.

```
class TopMenuTable: UITableView,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {


    var topArray  = [String]()


    convenience init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableViewStyle, items : [String]) {
        self.init(frame: frame, style:UITableViewStyle.Plain , items: [String]())

        self.scrollEnabled = false
        self.dataSource = self
        self.delegate = self
        self.topArray = items

        self.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }


    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return topArray.count
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")! as UITableViewCell
        //let cell : TopMenuCell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TopCell") as! TopMenuCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = topArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
```

Below is the code to initialise the TopMenuTable in ViewController :

```
    func menuButtonClicked(sender : UIButton){

        let topMenu = TopMenuTable.init(frame: CGRectMake(topMenuBtn.frame.origin.x - 100, 0, 260, 0), style: .Plain, items: topMenuItems)
        self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(topMenu)

    }


    EXE_BAD_ACCESS error is coming at this line.
    convenience init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableViewStyle, items : [String])
```

The same thing working fine in Obj c.( Below is the code)

```
    @implementation TopMenuTable

    -(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame style:(UITableViewStyle)style
    :(NSArray*)topArrayItems
    :(NSDictionary *)topDict{

    if (self == [super initWithFrame:frame style:style]) {
    [self setScrollEnabled:NO];
    topMenuItems = [topArrayItems mutableCopy];
    topMenuItemsDict = topDict;
    self.dataSource = self;
    self.delegate = self;

    }

    return self;

}
```

In View Controller i am initialising the code below.

```
topMenu = [[TopMenuTable alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(topMenuBtn.frame.origin.x - 100, 0, 260, 0) style:UITableViewStylePlain :topMenuItems :self.topMenuDictionary];
```

Comment: Obviously you're free to do whatever you want, but _why_ would you subclass UITableView? And even if you did, you can use the class into IB / Storyboard

Comment: `self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(topMenu)` this is very odd. You should not beadding stuff directly to navigation controller's view. If the code is in a view controller, it should be `self.view.addSubview(topMenu)` instead.

Comment: I have to use the single Table in multiple pages of the application,but with the different data in each page. Thats why i subclassed the UITableView.

Comment: Why are you passing items in init present inside the convenience initialiser. Will that not cause a infinite loop? You should be calling self.init(frame: frame, style:UITableViewStyle.Plain) inside the convenience initialiser.

Comment: @user1007352 That really is the wrong way to go about it. You'd be much better off subclassing `UITableViewController`

Answer (score 0):

I can see many problems in your code.

**First:** It should not be responsibility of the view to be its self delegate. A controller should be responsible for that. Using a TableViewController would be much clearer.

**Second:** Wrong us of the initializers. If you check your own code in objective c you are calling *[**super** initWithFrame:frame style:style]* you should do the same so that your initializer should look like

```
    init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableViewStyle, items : [String]) {
        super.init(frame: frame, style:style)

        self.scrollEnabled = false
        self.dataSource = self
        self.delegate = self
        self.topArray = items

        self.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }
```

Even if this would work, I recommend to follow a design pattern or your project will be affected by an entropy that will make it extremely hard to manage in the future.

**Third:** `self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(topMenu)` As I said before, I would recommend to have a view controller managing this view, and push this view controller onto the stack instead of manually manage this view as subview.

Those are just some of the problems I see here, but they are the most relevant ones. The crash is due to an infinite loop as the initializer is calling itself continuously. I hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

Your subclass declaration should be like this:

class MyTableView:UITableView{

var arrItems:[String] = []

```
convenience init(frame:CGRect,style:UITableViewStyle, items:[String]){

    self.init(frame:frame,style:style)
     self.arrItems = items
}
override init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableViewStyle) {
    super.init(frame: frame, style: style)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
 }
```

}